# Replace Data extension value with string, after lookup

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, journeybuilder

So i created an email, that is used in Journey Builder.

One of the variables that needs to be transmitted in an URL, is the ProductName. To keep it comprehensible for the customer, I would like to replace the actual value that is in the Data Extension, by a "cleaner version". I found the "Replace" function, but I'm not sure if this will work:

```javascript
SET @ProductName = Lookup("Test_B2C_Contracts_new_Filtered", "OptionProductCodes", "BPNumber", @BPNumber)
Replace (@ProductName,'AFFBEL','Belgium')
Replace (@ProductName,'AFFWORLD','World')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the result of the replace-function to the variable you like the final string to be in.

so this should work:

```javascript
SET @ProductName = Lookup("Test_B2C_Contracts_new_Filtered", "OptionProductCodes", "BPNumber", @BPNumber)
SET @ProductName = Replace (@ProductName,'AFFBEL','Belgium')
SET @ProductName = Replace (@ProductName,'AFFWORLD','World')
```

**Related documentation:**

- [AMPscript documentation: Replace-Function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Replace.htm)

Comment: You are welcome! If it works, please mark my answer as accepted, so other users can easily see this has been resolved.